# How can i draw a part of an image on top of a html page depending on my mouse movement? (with or without canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I want to draw an image on top of my html page depending on my mouse movement.
How can i do that? Is it a better approach to put the image below the rest of the html and scratch the html somehow away, or tu put the image above it and add it partially on top.

I found solutions on the internet with 2 images on top of each other where the top one is erased with canvas, but since i have multiple elements i want to overwrite, i have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you are wanting to do. Is this like a scratch card where an image gets slowly exposed as you scratch away at the page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've interpreted the question correctly, that the requirement is to allow the user to 'scratch away' at the page gradually revealing an image, you could do it either way.

There are libraries that will create a canvas of a page (or part thereof) such as htm2canvas. Using one of these you turn your page into an image, place it over the given image and remove (make transparent) pixels on the top canvas as the mouse moves. The drawback with this approach is that it's possible the conversion of the HTML to canvas isn't totally complete. There may be some aspects for example of CSS that aren't correctly rendered.

To be sure therefore it's probably better to do it the other way round. Lay a blank canvas over the page and copy the image to another canvas with the same dimensions but which is outside the viewport. As the mouse moves over the blank canvas copy the relevant pixels from the offscreen canvas to it.

If you could confirm that I've understood your question correctly I could go into more detail.